# PyQt error: No such signal QObject::dataChanged

Tags: qt, pyqt

PyQt application works fine, but when I close it Python shows this message:

```
"Object::connect: No such signal QObject::dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"
```

**What is the cause of this?** There isn't  a `dataChanged` signal in the program.

EDIT:
The MWE demonstrating the error:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
import ui_DBMainWindow

global Mw, Table
Id, Name, Size = range(3)

class TTable():
    pass

Table = TTable()

class TMainWindow(QMainWindow, ui_DBMainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        global Table
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.showMaximized()
        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setModel(Table.Model)  # if this line is commented out, error disappear

def main():
    global Mw, Table
    QApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    DB = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    DB.setDatabaseName("1.db")
    Table.Model = QSqlTableModel()
    Table.Model.setTable("MainTable")
    Table.Model.select()
    Mw = TMainWindow()
    QApp.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

EDIT 2: `1.db` is the database with table `MainTable` with 3 fields: `Id` (autoincrement hidden integer key), `Name` (string), `Size` (integer). It can be empty, the same error.

file `ui_DBMainWindow.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:\blizzard\Projects\PyQt\DB4\DBMainWindow.ui'
#
# Created: Fri Mar 26 22:04:00 2010
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.4.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 696)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.TableView = QtGui.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.TableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 551, 451))
        self.TableView.setObjectName("TableView")
        self.btAdd = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btAdd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 20, 91, 24))
        self.btAdd.setObjectName("btAdd")
        self.btDel = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btDel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 80, 91, 24))
        self.btDel.setObjectName("btDel")
        self.btEdit = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 50, 91, 24))
        self.btEdit.setObjectName("btEdit")
        self.leQueryError = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.leQueryError.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 550, 551, 20))
        self.leQueryError.setObjectName("leQueryError")
        self.btQuery = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btQuery.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 480, 75, 24))
        self.btQuery.setObjectName("btQuery")
        self.teQuery = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.teQuery.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 480, 551, 64))
        self.teQuery.setObjectName("teQuery")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 19))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "База данных", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btAdd.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Добавить", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btDel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Удалить", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btEdit.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Редактировать", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btQuery.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Запрос", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Comment: Provide full example, please, this script does not contain ui_DBMainWindow and references to 1.db. What it should be?

Answer (score 1):

can you provide some code from your application?
is there any instances of the following types or their descendants in it?
    `QAbstractItemModel`, `QAbstractItemView`, for example `QListView`, `QTreeView` and so one. Try to catch any places, where you connect something to ones, not especially to that signal. You need to look, when these descendant types instanced in your code emit `dataChanged`, thanks God, Qt is opensource.
    It seems, that your application thinks, that some object is QAbstractItemModel or QAbstractItemView descendant, whether it is not, and tries to connect a slot to its `dataChanged` signal.

PS. When you compile some interface by uic, the resulting class inherits from `object`, not `QtGui.QMainWindow` or smth. Maybe it is somehow related.

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods you are calling tries to connect a slot to a signal named `dataChanged` on a `QObject`, which obviously does not emit such a signal. Since there is no `dataChanged` signal in your program, chances are that some method tries to do it indirectly. Also, since it happens when you are closing your program, I would first look at the code that gets executed when the interpreter shuts down (i.e. destructors and such).